# What is the C# version of VB.NET's InputBox?

Tags: c#, vb.net

What is the C# version of VB.NET's `InputBox`?

Answer (score 270, accepted):

Add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic`, `InputBox` is in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction` namespace:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
string input = Interaction.InputBox("Prompt", "Title", "Default", x_coordinate, y_coordinate);
```

Only the first argument for `prompt` is mandatory

Comment: What if I want to get password from user?

Comment: @hims056 `InputBox` does not natively support masked input. You will need to roll your own input form.

Comment: Just import `using Microsoft.VisualBasic` so you just write `Interaction.InputBox()`

Comment: Can the VB input box be given a value to be filled in there from the start? (edit) Nevermind, that's the "default", I see.

Comment: I have searched for this at least 10 times. Always resulting on this answer. Would upvote again if I could. Thanks!

Comment: Note: this [doesn't work in .NET Core 3.1](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1162)

Comment: is there any way we can control the size of the InputBox?

Comment: @HimanshuJansari For .NET Framework, you can mask input using `PasswordChar`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-create-a-password-text-box-with-the-windows-forms-textbox-control

Answer (score 141):

Dynamic creation of a dialog box. You can customize to your taste.

*Note there is no external dependency here except winform*

```
private static DialogResult ShowInputDialog(ref string input)
    {
        System.Drawing.Size size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 70);
        Form inputBox = new Form();

        inputBox.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
        inputBox.ClientSize = size;
        inputBox.Text = "Name";

        System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
        textBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(size.Width - 10, 23);
        textBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 5);
        textBox.Text = input;
        inputBox.Controls.Add(textBox);

        Button okButton = new Button();
        okButton.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
        okButton.Name = "okButton";
        okButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        okButton.Text = "&OK";
        okButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(size.Width - 80 - 80, 39);
        inputBox.Controls.Add(okButton);

        Button cancelButton = new Button();
        cancelButton.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
        cancelButton.Name = "cancelButton";
        cancelButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        cancelButton.Text = "&Cancel";
        cancelButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(size.Width - 80, 39);
        inputBox.Controls.Add(cancelButton);

        inputBox.AcceptButton = okButton;
        inputBox.CancelButton = cancelButton; 

        DialogResult result = inputBox.ShowDialog();
        input = textBox.Text;
        return result;
    }
```

usage

```
string input="hede";
ShowInputDialog(ref input);
```

Comment: inputBox.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent; will center the dialog on the parent window.

Comment: The form is not visible when used in unit testing, this post will be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218517/very-strange-bug-when-using-show-dialog-on-c-sharp-winform

Comment: I prefer `FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow` as it prevents maximising and minimising.

Comment: Thank You! Added as well the inputBox.MinimizeBox = false;
            inputBox.MaximizeBox = false;
            inputBox.ShowInTaskbar = false;

Comment: This should be marked as the answer, it's perfect! I've take this and customized the heck out of it to allow for custom inputs, like the title of the form, etc.

Comment: How do I get the value of the input when calling this method?

Comment: @NeungChung it'll be in `input` after the `ShowInputDialog` box is closed. That's why it uses `ref`.

Answer (score 116):

To sum it up:

- There is [none in C#](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=c%23+inputbox).
- You can use the dialog from Visual Basic by adding a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic:

  1. In **Solution Explorer** right-click on the **References** folder.
  2. Select **Add Reference...**
  3. In the **.NET** tab (in newer Visual Studio verions - **Assembly** tab) - select **Microsoft.VisualBasic**
  4. Click on **OK**

Then you can use the previously mentioned code:

```
string input = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Prompt", "Title", "Default", 0, 0);
```

- Write your own InputBox.
- Use [someone else's](http://www.reflectionit.nl/Articles/InputBox.aspx).

That said, I suggest that you consider the need of an input box in the first place. Dialogs are not always the best way to do things and sometimes they do more harm than good - but that depends on the particular situation.

Comment: +1 for the the link Tomas posted. This one is better than the Virtual Basic InputBox.

Comment: Still better than using  /subsystem:console...  Sometimes you just need very little interaction with the user, and then you can use them, instead of having 90% of your code be for UI.

Comment: I chose the "Use someone else's" option and am happy with the result, from this one: http://www.reflectionit.nl/blog/2003/c-inputbox.  Reason I chose that one was the absence of hardcoded size/location values.  Also promising, is http://www.csharp-examples.net/inputbox-class/. Both these first two have validation of the entered text.  The accepted answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427020/prompt-dialog-in-windows-forms also looks good, but does not include the input validation feature.

Comment: The statement "There is none in C#" is misleading at best... these are not language features, they are framework features which are essentially language independent. The only thing "not C#" about it is the namespace, which is merely a label for human consumption.

Answer (score 9):

There isn't one. If you really wanted to use the VB InputBox in C# you can. Just add reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll and you'll find it there.

But I would suggest to *not* use it. It is ugly and outdated IMO.

Comment: I think you are being too kind. It's far more ugly and outdated than that!

Comment: Can't identify the `cancel` from `empty input string` actually is a bug IMO.

Answer (score 6):

Returns the string the user entered; empty string if they hit <kbd>Cancel</kbd>:

```
    public static String InputBox(String caption, String prompt, String defaultText)
    {
        String localInputText = defaultText;
        if (InputQuery(caption, prompt, ref localInputText))
        {
            return localInputText;
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Returns the `String` as a **ref** parameter, returning `true` if they hit <kbd>OK</kbd>, or `false` if they hit <kbd>Cancel</kbd>:

```
    public static Boolean InputQuery(String caption, String prompt, ref String value)
    {
        Form form;
        form = new Form();
        form.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font;
        form.Font = SystemFonts.IconTitleFont;

        SizeF dialogUnits;
        dialogUnits = form.AutoScaleDimensions;

        form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
        form.MinimizeBox = false;
        form.MaximizeBox = false;
        form.Text = caption;

        form.ClientSize = new Size(
                    Toolkit.MulDiv(180, dialogUnits.Width, 4),
                    Toolkit.MulDiv(63, dialogUnits.Height, 8));

        form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

        System.Windows.Forms.Label lblPrompt;
        lblPrompt = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        lblPrompt.Parent = form;
        lblPrompt.AutoSize = true;
        lblPrompt.Left = Toolkit.MulDiv(8, dialogUnits.Width, 4);
        lblPrompt.Top = Toolkit.MulDiv(8, dialogUnits.Height, 8);
        lblPrompt.Text = prompt;

        System.Windows.Forms.TextBox edInput;
        edInput = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        edInput.Parent = form;
        edInput.Left = lblPrompt.Left;
        edInput.Top = Toolkit.MulDiv(19, dialogUnits.Height, 8);
        edInput.Width = Toolkit.MulDiv(164, dialogUnits.Width, 4);
        edInput.Text = value;
        edInput.SelectAll();


        int buttonTop = Toolkit.MulDiv(41, dialogUnits.Height, 8);
        //Command buttons should be 50x14 dlus
        Size buttonSize = Toolkit.ScaleSize(new Size(50, 14), dialogUnits.Width / 4, dialogUnits.Height / 8);

        System.Windows.Forms.Button bbOk = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        bbOk.Parent = form;
        bbOk.Text = "OK";
        bbOk.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        form.AcceptButton = bbOk;
        bbOk.Location = new Point(Toolkit.MulDiv(38, dialogUnits.Width, 4), buttonTop);
        bbOk.Size = buttonSize;

        System.Windows.Forms.Button bbCancel = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        bbCancel.Parent = form;
        bbCancel.Text = "Cancel";
        bbCancel.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        form.CancelButton = bbCancel;
        bbCancel.Location = new Point(Toolkit.MulDiv(92, dialogUnits.Width, 4), buttonTop);
        bbCancel.Size = buttonSize;

        if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            value = edInput.Text;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Multiplies two 32-bit values and then divides the 64-bit result by a 
    /// third 32-bit value. The final result is rounded to the nearest integer.
    /// </summary>
    public static int MulDiv(int nNumber, int nNumerator, int nDenominator)
    {
        return (int)Math.Round((float)nNumber * nNumerator / nDenominator);
    }
```

> **Note**: Any code is released into the public domain. No attribution required.

Comment: public static int MulDiv(int number, int numerator, int denominator)
{
    return (int)(((long)number * numerator + (denominator >> 1)) / denominator);
}

Comment: What is ``Toolkit``?

Comment: @markusL Toolkit was my class that holds an implementation of `MulDiv`. You can see Peter's comment for an example implementation of `MulDiv`.

Comment: what is Toolkit.ScaleSize?

Comment: OK. it seems to be: Size buttonSize = new Size(MulDiv(50, (int)dialogUnits.Width, 4), MulDiv(14, (int)dialogUnits.Height, 8));

Answer (score 5):

Not only should you add `Microsoft.VisualBasic` to your reference list for the project, but also you should declare `using Microsoft.VisualBasic;` so you just have to use `Interaction.Inputbox("...")` instead of `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.Inputbox`.

Comment: If you're only using it once, this adds clutter if the OP decides they don't want the InputBox anymore. Also, this should be a comment.

Answer (score 4):

Add reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic` and use this function:

```
string response =  Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("What's 1+1?", "Title", "2", 0, 0);
```

The last 2 number is an X/Y position to display the input dialog.

Answer (score 3):

You mean InputBox?  Just look in the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace.

C# and VB.Net share a common library.  If one language can use it, so can the other.

Answer (score 3):

Without adding a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic:

```
// "dynamic" requires reference to Microsoft.CSharp
Type tScriptControl = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("ScriptControl");
dynamic oSC = Activator.CreateInstance(tScriptControl);

oSC.Language = "VBScript";
string sFunc = @"Function InBox(prompt, title, default) 
InBox = InputBox(prompt, title, default)    
End Function
";
oSC.AddCode(sFunc);
dynamic Ret = oSC.Run("InBox", "メッセージ", "タイトル", "初期値");
```

See these for further information:
[ScriptControl](http://www.geocities.jp/maru3128/SakuraMacro/usage/scriptcontrol.html)
[MsgBox in JScript](http://with-love-from-siberia.blogspot.ch/2009/12/msgbox-inputbox-in-jscript.html)
[Input and MsgBox in JScript](http://cwestblog.com/2012/03/10/jscript-using-inputbox-and-msgbox/)

.NET 2.0:

```
string sFunc = @"Function InBox(prompt, title, default) 
InBox = InputBox(prompt, title, default)    
End Function
";

Type tScriptControl = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("ScriptControl");
object oSC = Activator.CreateInstance(tScriptControl);

// https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System/MonoType.cs
// System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi = tScriptControl.GetProperty("Language", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.CreateInstance| System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
// pi.SetValue(oSC, "VBScript", null);

tScriptControl.InvokeMember("Language", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, oSC, new object[] { "VBScript" });
tScriptControl.InvokeMember("AddCode", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, oSC, new object[] { sFunc });
object ret = tScriptControl.InvokeMember("Run", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, oSC, new object[] { "InBox", "メッセージ", "タイトル", "初期値" });
Console.WriteLine(ret);
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve this by coding my own. I don't like extending into and relying on large library's for something rudimental.

Form and Designer:

```
public partial class InputBox 
    : Form
{

    public String Input
    {
        get { return textInput.Text; }
    }

    public InputBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
    }

    private void InputBox_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ActiveControl = textInput;
    }

    public static DialogResult Show(String title, String message, String inputTitle, out String inputValue)
    {
        InputBox inputBox = null;
        DialogResult results = DialogResult.None;

        using (inputBox = new InputBox() { Text = title })
        {
            inputBox.labelMessage.Text = message;
            inputBox.splitContainer2.SplitterDistance = inputBox.labelMessage.Width;
            inputBox.labelInput.Text = inputTitle;
            inputBox.splitContainer1.SplitterDistance = inputBox.labelInput.Width;
            inputBox.Size = new Size(
                inputBox.Width,
                8 + inputBox.labelMessage.Height + inputBox.splitContainer2.SplitterWidth + inputBox.splitContainer1.Height + 8 + inputBox.button2.Height + 12 + (50));
            results = inputBox.ShowDialog();
            inputValue = inputBox.Input;
        }

        return results;
    }

    void labelInput_TextChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }

}

partial class InputBox
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.labelMessage = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.labelInput = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.textInput = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.splitContainer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer();
        this.splitContainer2 = new System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.splitContainer1)).BeginInit();
        this.splitContainer1.Panel1.SuspendLayout();
        this.splitContainer1.Panel2.SuspendLayout();
        this.splitContainer1.SuspendLayout();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.splitContainer2)).BeginInit();
        this.splitContainer2.Panel1.SuspendLayout();
        this.splitContainer2.Panel2.SuspendLayout();
        this.splitContainer2.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // labelMessage
        // 
        this.labelMessage.AutoSize = true;
        this.labelMessage.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 0);
        this.labelMessage.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(379, 0);
        this.labelMessage.Name = "labelMessage";
        this.labelMessage.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 13);
        this.labelMessage.TabIndex = 99;
        this.labelMessage.Text = "Message";
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(316, 126);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 3;
        this.button1.Text = "Cancel";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        // 
        // button2
        // 
        this.button2.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(235, 126);
        this.button2.Name = "button2";
        this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button2.TabIndex = 2;
        this.button2.Text = "OK";
        this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
        // 
        // labelInput
        // 
        this.labelInput.AutoSize = true;
        this.labelInput.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 6);
        this.labelInput.Name = "labelInput";
        this.labelInput.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(31, 13);
        this.labelInput.TabIndex = 99;
        this.labelInput.Text = "Input";
        this.labelInput.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.labelInput_TextChanged);
        // 
        // textInput
        // 
        this.textInput.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.textInput.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
        this.textInput.Name = "textInput";
        this.textInput.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(243, 20);
        this.textInput.TabIndex = 1;
        // 
        // splitContainer1
        // 
        this.splitContainer1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.splitContainer1.FixedPanel = System.Windows.Forms.FixedPanel.Panel2;
        this.splitContainer1.IsSplitterFixed = true;
        this.splitContainer1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.splitContainer1.Name = "splitContainer1";
        // 
        // splitContainer1.Panel1
        // 
        this.splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(this.labelInput);
        // 
        // splitContainer1.Panel2
        // 
        this.splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(this.textInput);
        this.splitContainer1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(379, 50);
        this.splitContainer1.SplitterDistance = 126;
        this.splitContainer1.TabIndex = 99;
        // 
        // splitContainer2
        // 
        this.splitContainer2.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.splitContainer2.IsSplitterFixed = true;
        this.splitContainer2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
        this.splitContainer2.Name = "splitContainer2";
        this.splitContainer2.Orientation = System.Windows.Forms.Orientation.Horizontal;
        // 
        // splitContainer2.Panel1
        // 
        this.splitContainer2.Panel1.Controls.Add(this.labelMessage);
        // 
        // splitContainer2.Panel2
        // 
        this.splitContainer2.Panel2.Controls.Add(this.splitContainer1);
        this.splitContainer2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(379, 108);
        this.splitContainer2.SplitterDistance = 54;
        this.splitContainer2.TabIndex = 99;
        // 
        // InputBox
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(403, 161);
        this.Controls.Add(this.splitContainer2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
        this.MaximizeBox = false;
        this.MinimizeBox = false;
        this.Name = "InputBox";
        this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Text = "Title";
        this.TopMost = true;
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.InputBox_Load);
        this.splitContainer1.Panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.splitContainer1.Panel1.PerformLayout();
        this.splitContainer1.Panel2.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.splitContainer1.Panel2.PerformLayout();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.splitContainer1)).EndInit();
        this.splitContainer1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.splitContainer2.Panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.splitContainer2.Panel1.PerformLayout();
        this.splitContainer2.Panel2.ResumeLayout(false);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.splitContainer2)).EndInit();
        this.splitContainer2.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Label labelMessage;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label labelInput;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textInput;
    private System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer splitContainer1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer splitContainer2;
}
```

Usage:

```
String output = "";

result = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.None;

result = InputBox.Show(
    "Input Required",
    "Please enter the value (if available) below.",
    "Value",
    out output);

if (result != System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    return;
}
```

Note this exhibits a bit of auto sizing to keep it pretty based on how much text you ask it display. I also know it's lacking the bells and whistles but it's a solid step forward for those facing this same dilemma.

Answer (score -4):

There is no such thing: I recommend to write it for yourself and use it whenever you need.