# form that is already visible cannot be displayed as a modal dialog box

Tags: c#, winforms

In my program I open every form with the help of `ShowDialog` and close previous one with the help of:

```
this.Hide();
...some code...
this.Close();
```

But when I want to open Form for a second time, I get the error that is in the title. What can it be? Maybe it's because I use Singleton patter for that form that I want to open for a second time.

Comment: there is a lot of code, I even don't know what to include. As I understand the problem in ShowDialog

Answer (score 0):

Instead of continually showing forms using `ShowDialog` you can just create new instances of each form as you need them. For example

```
using(Form frm = new Form1)
{
   DialogResult dr = frm.ShowDialog(this)
   if(dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
   {
     ...
   }
}
```

or

```
Form frm = new Form1();
DialogResult dr = frm.ShowDialog(this);
if(dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
{
  ...
}
frm.Dispose();
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1218575/115272)

Comment: What to do with Singleton pattern form? I call it Form1.Instance.ShowDialog().

Comment: Don't use Singleton. If your forms are taking a long time to create, you should identify what resource is taking so long to load and cache that as a static object, instead of trying to cache the entire form as static.