# Show input dialog in WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, modal-dialog

I'd like to show an input modal in my WinForm application. I have looked around the web, but haven't found a good pattern for doing this. I understand I'd have to create another Form, and use the ShowDialog method.

Comment: http://www.reflectionit.nl/Articles/InputBox.aspx has an example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17546909/740639 is another example Input Prompt class that you can copy and paste.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are correct.

Note that modal dialogs are not automatically disposed when closed (unlike non-modal dialogs), so you want a pattern like:

```
using (FrmModal myForm = new FrmModal())
{
    DialogResult dr = myForm.ShowDialog();
    if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // ...
    }
    else
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In the new form itself (which I have called FrmModal), set the DialogResult property in your button event handlers appropriately, e.g. if you have an OK button you would want to set DialogResult = DialogResult.OK in the event handler for that button and then call Close() to close the form.

Comment: Small comment: Setting a Forms DialogResult != none is enough to close it.