# What's the simplest way to ask for user input through Modal in Win Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

What is the simplest way to implement a Modal(popup) `MessageBox` that allows a custom value to be entered and returned.  In my case, a `String`.

Maybe I am over thinking this but I figured I'd ask.  I plan to just create a new Form.  Add a `label`, a `textbox`, two `buttons`.  Assign the `textbox` to a `property` and from my main `form` call a `ShowDialog()` on it.

Will I be able to still access the `property` that way or should I somehow return the value?

Is this a decent way of doing this?

Comment: You may want to look for other options, though. Modality in an interface is generally not the best solution if it can be avoided. Especially modal dialog boxes asking to enter a single value smell more like remnants of the old text-mode terminal prompt/input dialog way of handling user input.

Comment: @Johannes Rossel:  I agree but we don't always set our own requirements. ;) Hence, winforms to SQL in the first place.  Do you have an alternative that I might slip under the radar?

Comment: I have no idea how your application looks like; so, no. But usually such modal input dialogs are a sign of a flawed interaction model which may need some more thought. Bu yes, if the requirements are there there probably isn't too much to do about that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show input dialog in WinForms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387236/show-input-dialog-in-winforms)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like a decent way to go except for exposing the TextBox as a property.  You should only need to expose TextBox.Text.

Answer (score 2):

Yes I actually do this, I made an input form that contains exactly what you said.

Lets call your property `InputValue`

```
using (ModalInputForm inputForm = new ModalInputForm()) {
 if (inputForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Ok) {
  _fieldToUse = inputForm.InputValue;
 }
}
```

Comment: You *have* to pay attention to the return value of ShowDialog().

Comment: @nobugz this is very valid. Edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

You will still be able to access the form's properties after the form has closed as long as your form variable is still in scope on the main form.

You could do something like this:

```
    frmPrompt frm = new frmPrompt();

    if ( frm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK )
    {
        string result = frm.SomeProperty
    }
```

Comment: A using statement is required here to dispose the form.

Comment: Yes, the form needs to be properly disposed of - either by enclosing it in a Using statement or disposing of it manually with frm.Dispose().  I didn't really think it was critical to the question being asked.