# C#, does it have a prompt box?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, prompt

Does C# have a code that makes a prompt box appear so that you can insert a value on it?
Like a messageBox but with a text field, like the one that javaScript has.

Or do I have to create a form for it?

Comment: What kind of app are you writing? Is this a Windows Forms application, or an ASP.NET app, or a Windows Communication Foundation app, or a console application, or what?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prompt Dialog in Windows Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427020/prompt-dialog-in-windows-forms)

Comment: `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox()`

Comment: How is this not a real question? It may or may not be a duplicate, but the question is clear enough! (and the answer is appropriate!)

Comment: I did some research and didn't find any post with the keywords I used, sorry for re-asking it though...
Either way, thanks for the answers, now I know ;)
Also I am using windows forms C# (Visual studio 2008), not Visual Basic

Comment: There is no build in functionality like that, that I know of.  See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383855(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I really don't understand how can someone vote for close "not a real question" and vote down the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [InputBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.inputbox.aspx) method from VisualBasic Interaction class.

Comment: thanks but I am currently programming in C#

Comment: There is no problem with C#. You only reference the Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll and then you can use the function. The Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll is core assembly in .NET Framework, so it's allways available.