# C# Windows form. How to use the button_click method?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using a for loop to keep adding items to an array by keep pressing the button, i call it btnEnter, after input some data.
something like

```
            double[] inputarr = new double[10];
            for (int i = 0; i < inputarr.Length; i++)
            {
                inputarr[i] = Double.Parse(txtAmount.Text);

            }
```

I want to jump out from the loop and perform something by clicking another button. Can button_click() do the job for me?
like

```
            for (int i = 0; i < inputarr.Length; i++)
            {
                inputarr[i] = Double.Parse(txtAmount.Text);
                if (btnStop_Click() == true)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
```

how to make this work? can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You shouldn't need to go to the UI for automation logic.  If you need to automatically "click a button" from within code, then what you _actually_ need is to extract the business logic from the button's click handler into a common method and automatically call that method.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to prompt for input 10 times in a row.  You're thought process is a bit inverted.  I think all you need is a prompt dialog.  See [Prompt Dialog in Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427020/prompt-dialog-in-windows-forms) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can call another button like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < inputarr.Length; i++)
        {
            inputarr[i] = Double.Parse(txtAmount.Text);
            btnStop_Click(null,null);
                break;
            }
        }
```

or u can use timer

```
  int i = 0;Timer t = new Timer();
 button_click(object sender,event e)
  {

        t.Interval = 4000;
        t.Tick += t_Tick;
        t.Start();
  }
  void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (i <= 9) { inputarr[i] = Double.Parse(txtAmount.Text); }

        else { t.Stop(); Do other staff  }
        i++;
    }
```