# C# - edit text property for tab pages at runtime

Tags: c#, edit, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have a tab control to which I can add new tab pages typing in a textbox the name to be showed for each tab. What i want to do is to be able to right click on a tab and rename it (to allow me to edit the text), like the option in many other apps... I have a "remove tab" option already in place and working but I cannot find  a way to rename the selected tab..

Any help is much appreciated!

this is my code for remove option if can be at any help..

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
        cm.MenuItems.Add("Remove", new EventHandler(rmv_click));
        cm.MenuItems.Add("Rename");
        tabControl1.ContextMenu = cm;


    }
//select tab on right mouse click
        private void tabControl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < this.tabControl1.TabCount; ++i)
                {
                    if (this.tabControl1.GetTabRect(i).Contains(new Point(e.X, e.Y)))
                    {
                        this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

//remove selected tab
    private void rmv_click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabControl1.SelectedTab);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this: (quick and dirty)

```
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
            cm.MenuItems.Add("Remove", new EventHandler(rmv_click));
            cm.MenuItems.Add("Rename", new EventHandler(rename_click));
            tabControl1.ContextMenu = cm;
        }

        //select tab on right mouse click
        private void tabControl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < this.tabControl1.TabCount; ++i)
                {
                    if (this.tabControl1.GetTabRect(i).Contains(new Point(e.X, e.Y)))
                    {
                        this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //remove selected tab
        private void rmv_click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabControl1.SelectedTab);
        }

        //rename selected tab
        private void rename_click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var showDialog = this.ShowDialog("Tab Name", "Rename the selected tab");
            tabControl1.SelectedTab.Text = showDialog;
        }

        public string ShowDialog(string text, string caption)
        {
            Form prompt = new Form();
            prompt.Width = 500;
            prompt.Height = 150;
            prompt.Text = caption;
            Label textLabel = new Label() { Left = 50, Top = 20, Text = text };
            TextBox textBox = new TextBox() { Left = 50, Top = 50, Width = 400 };
            Button confirmation = new Button() { Text = "Ok", Left = 350, Width = 100, Top = 70 };
            confirmation.Click += (sender, e) => { prompt.Close(); };
            prompt.Controls.Add(confirmation);
            prompt.Controls.Add(textLabel);
            prompt.Controls.Add(textBox);
            prompt.ShowDialog();
            return textBox.Text;
        }
```

credits for ShowDialog Method to Bas Brekelmans. Orginal could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427020/prompt-dialog-in-windows-forms)

Comment: Thank for the answer, works fine :)
But I was looking actually for a solution to edit the name directly without opening a new window.  Anyway I will use your solution to continue with the other functions and when I will have time, I will look into this deeper.