# Enter Text in PopUp Box

Tags: c#

I'd like my prog to pop up a box in which the user can enter text to store it in a variable.
Do i have to create a new form for this?

Comment: Is this a web app? Winforms?  What have you tried so far?  We need something to work with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only need to input one string at a time, you could use [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.inputbox.aspx).

If you need to be able to input more than one string or other things (like a selection from a dropbox or a date from a calendar), you will need to implement your own control.

**Update:** [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97097/what-is-the-c-version-of-vb-nets-inputdialog) is an SO question that will help you out a bit more. It's fairly similar to yours in that the answer is the same, but I think your question is different enough to not be considered a duplicate.

Comment: He isn't using VB, he is using C#, take a look at the tags.

Comment: @DalexL I did look at the tags and my suggestion IS C#. Please look at links before trying to rip them apart.