# InputDialog for C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am busy with an exercise where I want to have an InputDialog where user can input information.
I presume that there is no C# version for InputDialog found with java and what I did was to add an extra Windows Form and call it in a button click event.

The problem I have is that a thread also needs to fire in the same event and wanted to ask advice on how to receive the user data(this case name) before I call the thread?

```
private void butStartThread_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name;
        //opening the 'InputDialog'
        new Form2().Show();
        ////retrieving the name received from Input Dialog
        name = NameClass.Name;
        //thread called in same handler
        Thread randomImages = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.chooseRandomImage));

        randomImages.Start();
        labUserName.Text = name;
     }
```

I am relatively inexperienced so is there an better way to do this?

Comment: You'll need to use ShowDialog() instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the C# version of VB.net's InputDialog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97097/what-is-the-c-sharp-version-of-vb-nets-inputdialog)

Answer (score 4):

```
string input = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Prompt", "Title", "Default", 0, 0);
```

There you go with your Inputdialog in C#, taken from VB ;)