# Converting VBScript snippet to C#

Tags: c#, vbscript, converters

I have looked through the code but I simply do not have the understanding to know what functions are doing what and how in relation to C# my primary coding language.

```
Set mSkype = WScript.CreateObject("Skype4COM.Skype", "Skype_")

ContactName=InputBox ("Enter the contact's Skype User Name" & CHR(13) & "Note that this must be the User Name and not the Display Name", "User Name:")

If ContactName = "" Then
    WScript.Quit
Else
    If mSkype.User(ContactName).FullName="" then
        WScript.Echo ("The name " & ContactName & " is not in your Contact List")
        WScript.Quit
    End If  
End If


PictureFileName=InputBox ("Enter the path and name of the Picture" & CHR(13) & "The file extension must be .jpg", "Save Picture as:")

If PictureFileName="" Then
    WScript.Quit
End If


cmdStr = "GET USER" & " " & ContactName & " " & "AVATAR 1" & " " & PictureFileName
mSkype.SendCommand mSkype.Command(0, cmdStr)
```

Oh and I do have skype4com imported and im using that api, that is not the issue with conversion.

Comment: The job seems to be done here: http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/how-to-get-the-profile-picture-of-users-using-skype4com-api-with/td-p/444063

Answer (score 0):

InputBox is a window that displays that prompts for input.  It is available in VB.NET, and you can actually use it in C# by adding a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97097/what-is-the-c-sharp-version-of-vb-nets-inputdialog).

WScript is also not available in VB and it would probably be good to research how to use the Skype plugin in the Skype Developer Forum.  [Here](http://devforum.skype.com/t5/Desktop-API/Make-a-call-using-Skype4Com-and-C/td-p/19840)'s a link about how to use the Skype DLL in C#.