# Can I take a input from the user in a message box in C#?

Tags: c#

I need to ask a question for the user. I would like them to enter the ID who's record they want to see. The user should input the ID. How can I do that in C#?

Comment: Its not message box its input box. and what platform? asp.net or winforms or WPF?

Comment: Have you written any code yet? It would help us to give you an answer if we see what you have so far.

Comment: Maybe this'll help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97097/what-is-the-c-sharp-version-of-vb-nets-inputdialog

Comment: no i have not written any code. i want to do searching in database. for this reason i need an input from the user.

Comment: i m using visual C# express edition 2008

Comment: @user2202791, check this [SO Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97097/what-is-the-c-sharp-version-of-vb-nets-inputdialog)

Comment: Sorry gyz this didn't works....:(

Answer (score 1):

You need to use vb input box. Add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic, InputBox is in the Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction namespace

Add do something like:

```
 string input = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Prompt", "Title", "Default", 0, 0);
```

Comment: Sorry this didn't works

Comment: Have u added references to `Microsoft.VisualBasic` and `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction` namespaces?