# C# Windows Store App Input Box

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

i'm currently developing on Windows Store App using c# and .Net 4.5 on visual studio 2012. 
In my application i want to create input box like Microsoft made in their calendar app.

[image: what i want to make]

can i made this to? thanks, sorry for my bad English.

update :
i just followed instruction from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97097/what-is-the-c-sharp-version-of-vb-nets-inputdialog) and i got this error : 

*Error   1   The type or namespace name 'Interaction' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.VisualBasic' (are you missing an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\TestApp\MainPage.xaml.cs 41  50  TestApp*


 
I've referenced microsoft.visualbasic in my app, but it still error. Please help.

Comment: "Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking."

Comment: sorry, I accidentally hit the submit button ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Callisto toolkit](https://github.com/timheuer/callisto) has custom dialog, you can use that to create such dialog. You can use any UI element.

Use `xmlns:callisto="using:Callisto.Controls"` in `<Page />`

```xml
<callisto:CustomDialog x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="LoginDialog" 
                        Title="Bacon Terms and Conditions" 
                        Background="Teal" BackButtonVisibility="Visible">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,8" FontSize="14.6667" FontWeight="SemiLight" TextWrapping="Wrap">
            Bacon sausage frankfurter tenderloin turkey salami andouille bresaola. Venison salami prosciutto, pork belly turducken tri-tip spare ribs chicken strip steak fatback shankle tongue boudin andouille. Meatloaf salami pork ground round turkey jerky meatball ball tip, filet mignon fatback flank prosciutto shank. Turkey boudin ham hock, filet mignon tri-tip bresaola tongue venison spare ribs meatloaf flank beef pancetta. Leberkas turducken flank ground round biltong chuck bacon kielbasa. Beef pastrami meatball, short loin venison swine pork loin shank meatloaf spare ribs.
        </TextBlock>
        <CheckBox Margin="0,0,0,8" Foreground="White" Content="I agree to the Terms and Conditions of Bacon" />
        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,8" FontSize="14.6667" FontWeight="SemiLight" Text="Enter your name for acceptance" />
        <callisto:WatermarkTextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Watermark="Type your name" Width="400" Height="35" />
        <StackPanel Margin="0,20,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="OK" Width="90" Margin="0,0,20,0" />
            <Button Content="CANCEL" Width="90" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</callisto:CustomDialog>
```

The output will be like this.

[image]

[Callisto NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/Callisto)

[Callisto Visual Studio gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0526563b-7a48-4b17-a087-a35cea701052)

Comment: thanks for your reply, can i made input box in message dialog using  Callisto toolkit?

Comment: [MessageDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR208674) is totally different than Callisto's input dialog. You need to use CustomDialog from it. See my updated answer.

Comment: hey, thanks for you reply, but i got this error on BackButtonClicked="LoginDialog_BackButtonClicked_1" and Click="DialogCancelClicked" it said " Error 2 'App1.MainPage' does not contain a definition for 'DialogCancelClicked' and no extension method 'DialogCancelClicked' accepting a first argument of type 'App1.MainPage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\App1\MainPage.xaml"

Comment: It is showing error because your XAML is declaring the event but code behind is not having the event body. So either define the event or remove that (see the updated code in answer).