# How to call Input Dialog (Gorkem Gencay) from other class

Tags: c#, input

how can i use ['Gorkem Gencay' InputDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97097/what-is-the-c-sharp-version-of-vb-nets-inputdialog) calling it from another Class?
**Edit: Inserted all the code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace InputDialog
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static DialogResult ShowInputDialog(ref string input)
        {
            System.Drawing.Size size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 70);
            Form inputBox = new Form();

            inputBox.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
            inputBox.ClientSize = size;
            inputBox.Text = "Name";

            System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
            textBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(size.Width - 10, 23);
            textBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 5);
            textBox.Text = input;
            inputBox.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
            inputBox.Controls.Add(textBox);

            Button okButton = new Button();
            okButton.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
            okButton.Name = "okButton";
            okButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            okButton.Text = "&OK";
            okButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(size.Width - 80 - 80, 39);
            inputBox.Controls.Add(okButton);

            Button cancelButton = new Button();
            cancelButton.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
            cancelButton.Name = "cancelButton";
            cancelButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            cancelButton.Text = "&Cancel";
            cancelButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(size.Width - 80, 39);
            inputBox.Controls.Add(cancelButton);

            inputBox.AcceptButton = okButton;
            inputBox.CancelButton = cancelButton;

            DialogResult result = inputBox.ShowDialog();
            input = textBox.Text;
            return result;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string input = "hede";
            ShowInputDialog(ref input);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying the following **istead of using the private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)**, but don't work:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace InputDialog
{
    class Class1
    {
        Form1 frm = new Form1();
        string input = "hede";
        frm.ShowInputDialog(ref input);
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you create some public property inside of Form1, also you should have a constructor that perhaps takes input as a param when creating the new instance of Form1, you will need an InitializeComponent(); inside the constructor, this should be no different than if you  were to do it with windows calling frm.ShowDialoag()

Comment: I'm new to programming. Can you write some code? Thanks

Comment: wow...you'e asking someone to write code.. good luck.. I would suggest a new career path since you are too lazy to use google and try something on your own.. `I am new to programming is never an excuse`

Comment: I'm trying to learn by my self and also english is not my language. Thanks anyway

Comment: use google and search for `C# Basics Tutorials`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `ShowInputDialog` method is defined as static so you need to use class name and not an object name when calling it. Assuming `ShowInputDialog` is defined in the `Form1` class, you should invoke it as follows:

```
string input = "hede";
Form1.ShowInputDialog(ref input);
```

By the way, that method is defined as `private` so you have to make it `public` or `internal`.

The `Class1` definition also has an error. You can't call procedural code (`frm.ShowInputDialog(ref input);`) out of procedural context. Define a method and put your dialog invocation code it this method:

```
class Class1
{
    public static void TestDialogCall()
    {
        string input = "hede";
        Form1.ShowInputDialog(ref input);
    }
}
```

Comment: In this way, Form1.ShowInputDialog(ref input); is underlined of red and the error is: The name 'ShowInputDialog' does not exist in the actual context

Comment: Where `ShowInputDialog` is defined in your case?

Comment: Inside Form1: public static DialogResult ShowInputDialog(ref string input)

Comment: What about namespaces? Are there any colliding `Form1` class definitions?

Comment: When you compile your project what is the exact compilation error message?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144069/discussion-between-massimo-d-n-and-dmitry-egorov).

Comment: The problem is solved via chat. Thanks to Dmitry Egorov