# does c# winform has build-in input dialog?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am wondering if c# has build-in input dialog, this dialog only has one(or only a few) text input and OK and Cancel button.

So I don't need to add a new form for such a simple job.

Comment: I assume that you are talking about the framework and not the language itself, but then for what technology? WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET etc...

Comment: Winform, Thanks!

Comment: no you have to make your own

Comment: The duplicate answers your question, however I prefer to not add the reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic in my applications. So I have ended to copy [one of the many already done examples](https://www.bing.com/search?q=InputBox%20for%20C%23&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=inputbox%20for%20c%23&sc=1-15&sk=&cvid=122C3B118C9D498A92C4226D80509A1D) that you can retrieve on the net and put it a utility library that I can reuse in many apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show) to create a message box and specify that you only want an `Ok` and `Cancel` button:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
MessageBox.Show("Prompt", "Caption", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
```

The `Show` method returns the button clicked as a [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.dialogresult):

```
DialogResult rst = MessageBox.Show("Prompt", "Caption", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
if(rst == DialogResult.OK)
    MessageBox.Show("You clicked OK");
```

If you are asking how to create an input box, then the question has already been asked here [What is the C# version of VB.net's InputDialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97097/what-is-the-c-sharp-version-of-vb-nets-inputdialog), though I would recommend that you create your own version of an input box, because the VBA version is pretty ugly - that way you can also style the input box according to your desire.

Comment: I think the OP wants something where they can type some text and get the input back

Comment: @Steve If he wants to get the input back, then he is asking a duplicate question, and the question should be flagged as a duplicate. See [What is the C# version of VB.net's InputDialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97097/what-is-the-c-sharp-version-of-vb-nets-inputdialog).

Comment: _"though I would recommend that you create your own version of an input box."_  - why is that?

Comment: @MickyD Because the VBA version is pretty ugly. I usually create a simple form, that can be configured like a MessageBox can. I have updated the answer.